# Deploying PrimeFaces app to GlassFish4 causes java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/fileupload/FileItem

Tags: jsf, netbeans, primefaces, glassfish-4

I'd like to use `<p:calendar>` in my JSF app developed in Netbeans, so I added the PrimeFaces library. However, when I deploy the app, it errors as follows:

```
Context with name [/ManagedBeansWithComponents] has not yet been started
C:\Users\Dell-pc\Documents\NetBeansProjects\ManagedBeansWithComponents\nbproject\build-   impl.xml:1040: The module has not been deployed.
See the server log for details.
BUILD FAILED (total time: 1 second)
```

And the server log says:

```
Source Document: jar:file:/C:/Users/Dell-pc/Documents/NetBeansProjects/ManagedBeansWithComponents/build/web/WEB-INF/lib/primefaces-3.5.jar!/META-INF/faces-config.xml
Cause: Class 'org.primefaces.component.fileupload.FileUploadRenderer' is missing a runtime dependency: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/fileupload/FileItem
```

How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/fileupload/FileItem

There is the cause. It's crystal clear. The mentioned class is missing in the runtime classpath. The solution is rather straightforward: put the mentioned class (or, the JAR file containing it) in the runtime classpath. As the package name hints, it's available on http://commons.apache.org/fileupload (which in turn has by the way http://commons.apache.org/io as dependency). Just download and drop those JARs in the same place as PrimeFaces JAR and all should be well.

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, note that this particular problem is in turn unintented by PrimeFaces. This problem should actually only occur when you register the `FileUploadFilter` for the `<p:fileUpload>` component in `web.xml`. However, since GlassFish 4.0, it is overzealously preloading every single JSF component and renderer class found in the classpath even if it's never used by the application. The class loading in turn causes all its runtime dependencies to be checked. If it's missing, then you get the `NoClassDefFoundError`. This problem is thus specific to GlassFish 4.0 and does not occur when using GlassFish 3.x or any other servletcontainer such as Tomcat or JBoss.

Comment: I haven't use <p:fileUpload> component.Where can İ put prime-faces jar? Where is the runtime classpath?

Comment: I'm afraid you didn't understood the answer at all. I didn't said anywhere that you need to move the PrimeFaces JAR to a different place. I said that you need to add Apache Commons FileUpload (and IO) JARs. Exactly as stated in the end of the 1st paragraph.

Comment: The pieces of text in my answer which appears in a blue color are links. Carefully move your mouse pointer above those pieces of text until an underline appears and then firmly click the left button of the mouse. It'll open the link's target URL where you can find and download the JAR.